# ASP.NET MVC: CheckBox Status is not returned correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, checkbox, http-post

First of all I have to say that I am a beginner in ASP.NET :)

I have a simple page consisting of a checkbox and I want to return the result of this checkbox in MVC pattern in controller.

Here is my code - model:

```
public class CheckBoxOptionModel
{
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
     public string Description { get; set; }
     public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class TasksController : Controller
{
     public IActionResult Index()
     {
         var model = new CheckBoxOptionModel()
         {
             IsChecked = false,
             Description="CheckBox 1"
         };

         return View(model);
     }

     [HttpPost]
     public IActionResult Index(CheckBoxOptionModel model)
     {
         var isChecked = model.IsChecked;
         return RedirectToAction("Index");
     }
}
```

`.cshtml` view markup:

```
<form asp-controller="Tasks" asp-action="Index" method="post">
    <div class="form-check mb-3">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" asp-for="IsChecked"/>
        <label class="form-check-label" asp-for="IsChecked">
           @Model.Description
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

The result in the `[HttpPost]` is always false, even if I set my form to true.

Thanks for your help

I have tried various options in `.cshtml`, but unfortunately have not got any further.

Comment: I have found it. It was a beginner's mistake
Value=""